# ng-model input not updated in view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a text input in a `<form>` used as a search input.

On the right of this text input, I have a search icon if the input is empty, and a cross icon if there is text in the input.

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
   <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" ng-model="searchInput" id="sInput" class="form-control" 
             placeholder="{{isEnglish ? 'Search...' : 'Recherche...'}}" 
             ng-change="filterCartoList(searchInput)">

      <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button type='submit' name='search' id='search-btn' class="btn btn-flat">
            <span ng-if="searchInput.length == 0">
               <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </span>
            <span ng-if="searchInput.length > 0" ng-click="clearSearch(); filterCartoList('');">
               <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            </span>
         </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

I want my input to be cleared whenever I click on the cross icon.

So I use the `clearSearch()` function :

```
$scope.clearSearch = function () {
    $scope.searchInput = '';
};
```

The search is reset. But the input text still has the text in it.

When I display `searchInput` using `console.log($scope.searchInput)`, it is an empty string. But somehow, in my view, the text input still has the same value.

Also if I display `searchInput` somewhere in my page, it doesn't change neither after clicking on the cross icon, even if the search is well reset and the console shows an empty string for `searchInput`.

So I suppose, that I'm displaying a copy or something.

Any idea how to clear my input as well ?

Edit : I also tried `document.getElementById("sInput").innerHTML = "";` for the `clearSearch()` function and same issue.

Comment: What happens when you do `$scope.$apply()` after changing the value of `searchInput`?

Comment: Is your code inside of a directive or a child controller or something of the sort? Most likely, `searchInput` is shadowing the real `searchInput`, and `clearSearch()` is clearing the real `searchInput`, not the shadow copy.

Comment: @Agop : This form is inside a `<md-tab>` from angular material.

@Robin : The exact same thing occurs with `$scope.$apply();`

Comment: Try adding the dot notation, something like `$scope.myForm.searchInput` (instead of just searchInput). My guess is you are in a child scope and don't realize it. I set up a small example here and it works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/JKBbV/655/ . Are you passing searchInput through a directive or something?

Comment: I also prefer `ng-show` to `ng-if`.  I find that sometimes `ng-if` messes up databindings.  Probably not the actual problem here, but it's worth a try.

Comment: can you share `filterCartoList(searchInput)` js codes

Comment: @ajmajmajma What would be `myForm` in my case ? I mean with what syntax do I access it ?

@SheraliTurdiyev Editing inital post to add filterCartoList

Comment: I just made it up, all I am doing is adding a dot notion because you are probably within a child scope. Literally just try swapping all of your $scope.searchInput to $scope.myForm.searchInput and see if that works. It's hard to really say because the context outside of what you are showing here would determine that - but that is too much code to paste in here :).

Comment: Well, I still don't get what should I put after the dot in order to access the child scope

Comment: Literally in your example code you have pasted, replace `$scope.searchInput` with `$scope.myForm.searchInput` , all you are doing is adding a level, this is one of the big learning curve problems with angular. So on the html change ng-model="searchInput" to ng-model="myForm.searchInput" , in in the clear function   $scope.myForm.searchInput = ''; , I just made up the "myform" part you can replace that with whatever you want.  Check out this example - http://jsfiddle.net/JKBbV/659/ . If this is not the issue it is probably that second function you have there.

Comment: change it: `$scope.clearSearch = function () {
    $scope.searchInput = ''; 
     $scope.filterCartoList('')
};` and replace to `ng-click="clearSearch();"` in html file

Comment: I did that now because it makes more sense, but it doesn't fix it.

The dot notation neither, it would not have been a viable option anyway since I'm using searchInput elsewhere.

Comment: It is how you should get used to passing objects around in angular, say for example you pass searchInput down into a directive, you will have to use dot notation and add a level onto it or it will not work properly. I was just making a guess based on your example, and also because I can take your example code and throw it in a fiddle and it works fine. Hard to say what's wrong at this point if the dot notation does not fix. Maybe try taking off the filterCartoList function and testing. Based on the fact the sample code works in a fiddle, i believe you are missing some context.

Comment: To be very honest: your `ng-click="clearSearch();"` on the span is not triggering. If you move the ng-click to the button you'll see it triggers and clears the model, but renders the desired functionality obsolete. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yoGXCNNp8fheMLtctASm?p=preview) is a plunker with your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is actually a javascript function that will take care of this for you:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

So if you add this to your function (or use in an onclick which I know is no longer good form but still works in some scenarios).

```
$scope.clearSearch = function () {
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
};
```

This should have the same effect as you trying to clear all of your inputs.

Comment: If whoever -1 me would give an excuse as to why i'd be glad to edit my answer.  Please don't -1 without explaining why.  >_<

Comment: It seems to work.
Don't know why the other solutions doesn't though. Thanks !

Comment: The problem is, "" is still considered a string, just an empty one.  So it's still detecting a value. :)

Comment: Yea but it should have been updated to an empty one in the view too. Besides the pure js using innerHTML didn't work neither, anyway, i won't waste more time on thys ><, ty

Comment: But the view searchInput is still not updated, since the icon isnt reset until i type something and delete it.. But I'll use this trick for now

Comment: You just need to find wherever that icon reset is triggered at, and set it to whatever you need the trigger to be.  If it's currently set on the deletion of characters you need to look for a keycode, probably keycode == 8

Comment: No, it works just fine when i'm deleting the input using backspace, the icon is changed.
It is not changed when I call my clearSearch() function by clicking on the icon.

Comment: Hmm, it could be a number of things.  Were you the one who set the function up?